# Why's my Eloquent where() clause breaking my query when removed?

Tags: php, laravel, debugging

I have an Eloquent query where it allows the user to search for items using keywords successfully when the `->where('item.isAvailable', $boxChecked)` clause isn't present.

However, whenever I add the `->where('item.isAvailable', $boxChecked)` clause - it breaks my query in terms of no items showing up upon searching.  I believe the issue's because of the way that `where()`'s written but I'm not too sure.

Note:  `$boxChecked`'s just a boolean value. this `where()` clause's supposed to hide items that are unavailable.  The frontend has a checkbox.

How'd I correct this so that the user can search using keywords to find the item they need and be able to hide unavailable items if they want to without breaking the query?

Edit: I've tried using a closure but it still produced the same result :(.

Here's my Eloquent query:

```
$inventories = $this->model
                ->join('awards', 'item.ItemID', '=', 'awards.AwardLinkID')
                ->join('opps', 'awards.AwardID', '=', 'opps.AwardID')
                ->whereIn('item.ItemID', explode(',', $searchKeyword))
                ->orWhere('item.Description','like', "%{$searchKeyword}%")
                ->where('item.isAvailable', $boxChecked)
                ->groupBy('item.ItemID')
                ->select("item.ItemID", "item.Description", "opps.OppID")
                ->get();
```

Comment: is isAvailable a column in item table?

Comment: @Parsa_Gholipour yeah it's a column in item table

Comment: Your query seems fine

Comment: I believe your raw query output is something like this: `where in ... or ... and ...`. If this isn't what you want try dumping out the raw query and editing it in sql, then go back and adjust the laravel syntax.

Comment: You're mixing And/Or clauses. Figure out which needs to be [grouped together, and pass it into a Closure](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/queries#logical-grouping)

Comment: @aynber got it, thank you.